# dart onTouchMove compiled to JS delay

Tags: dart

I wonder what's wrong. In emulated chrome touch, it worked perfectly. In mobile compiled to JavaScript chrome browser, does not work perfectly.
*Tested on Android 4.1 - Chrome 30 - dual core
Dart Editor version 0.8.1_r28355
Dart SDK version 0.8.1.2_r28355*

```
import 'dart:html';

DivElement divContainer;

void main() {
  divContainer = new DivElement()
    ..style.backgroundColor = '#6a00d7'
    ..style.width = '600px'
    ..style.height = '600px';

  document.body.nodes.add(divContainer);

  window.onTouchMove.listen((event) => mov(event));
}

mov(evento){
  divContainer.innerHtml = evento.touches[0].client.x.toString();
}
```

Comment: And what exactly is the problem? "Doesn't work perfectly" isn't a very useful description...

Answer (score 0):

Add inside the method call:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Prevents shortcuts "touch" interfere (chrome mobile).
Method code:

```
mov(evento){
  evento.preventDefault();
  divContainer.innerHtml = evento.touches[0].client.x.toString();
}
```